# JavaFX When a predefined button is used in a for loop, it doesn't show up

Tags: java, javafx

I have a ListView and it contains an unknown amount of BorderPanes. To make these BorderPanes i am using a constructor which makes an ArrayList of them. Each BorderPane contains a has a Label on the left and 2 buttons on the right. The dates are always unique but the buttons are always the same, and i need to use them outside the constructor for button.setOnAction.

The problem is, if the Button is defined outside the for loop inside the constructor, the button will simply not appear on the list, if it is created inside the for loop it does.

Code with program open
[image]

```
public ArrayList<BorderPane> makeDateListInfo(String fileName, Button buttonDateDelete, Button buttonDateEdit) {
        ArrayList<String> dateArray = getDateArray(fileName);
        ArrayList<BorderPane> outputList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 1; i < dateArray.size(); i++) {
            String[] arrOfText = dateArray.get(i).split("Date: ");
            arrOfText = arrOfText[1].split("\n\nWeight:");
            String date = arrOfText[0];
            arrOfText = arrOfText[1].split(" Kg|Kg");
            String weight = arrOfText[0];

            BorderPane dateBorderPane = new BorderPane();
            Label dateInfo = new Label("Date: " + date +  "    Weight: " + weight);

            Button dateDelete = new Button("Delete");
            Button dateEdit = new Button("Edit");
            HBox buttons = new HBox();
            buttons.getChildren().addAll(dateDelete, dateEdit);

            dateBorderPane.setLeft(dateInfo);
            dateBorderPane.setRight(buttons);
            outputList.add(dateBorderPane);
        }
        return outputList;
    }
```

Code and program with the changed code
[image]

`Button buttonDateDelete, Button buttonDateEdit` are defined in the exact same way as inside the for loop outside of it, i don't understand why it doesn't show up.

If they aren't defined outside i can't really interact with the button anymore and tell it what to do.

Comment: If you declare and instantiate the button outside the loop, you're adding the same button multiple times to the scene, which is not allowed. It looks like this would be much better as a `TableView` anyway.

Comment: (Actually, you may see the one-and-only delete button and one-and-only edit button at the bottom, if you scroll all the way down.) As an aside, please don't post images of code. Post the altered code as a second code block, with the image of the results. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Thank you very much, the buttons are indeed at the bottom. Duly noted on the images!